# Internet Explorer 11: How to save usernames in forms but never save passwords (and never show the notification)

Tags: windows-10, passwords, internet-explorer-11, username

When I connect on websites using Internet Explorer 11, it proposes me to save the entered password. I don't want to save passwords, because my passwords are managed in an external application, and I don't want my credentials to be stored in the Windows Web Credentials store. So each time I connect I have to click on the "Not for this site" button.

[image]

I know that I can disable the password saving in Internet Explorer, if I uncheck this option:
Internet Options > Contents > AutoComplete > Click on [Settings] > 
Uncheck "User names and passwords on forms"

But if I do so, my usernames are no more stored in forms (No AutoComplete). This worries me because this is a very useful feature which allows me to quickly authenticate on the login forms.

**So here is my question:**
How can we still store the usernames in forms and having Internet Explorer never display the annoying notification "Would you like to store your password for ..."?

For reference, here is the Microsoft documentation on how to configure passwords saving in web forms (but it does not provide any solution to my issue):
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17499/windows-internet-explorer-11-remember-passwords-fill-out-web-forms

Answer (score 0):

You could script the form submission, rather than allowing the default submit button behavior. This would than allow you to auto-fill your username fields as normal, but when in come to saving the password, IE can be setup to "think" the password is NOT a password if you use a hidden field instead to submit the password. I haven't exactly tried to do any of this, but you may also need to move your password field outside of the containing form element to get IE to ignore it on submission.

Comment: Your answer is off topic. I don't talk about a form that I would have coded for my website. I talk about forms found on the whole internet, for instance the search input boxes found on a lot of websites...

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood your question. I don't think you'll be able to accomplish what you are attempting to do without directly modifying the site(s) in question. What you want isn't really what credential storage was designed for. Auto-complete, maybe, but again, something that would need to be customized by site engineering.